# Using Spring ACL in a complicated access setup for an entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, acl

I am developing a spring boot application with `spring-data-rest` being one of the core dependencies. As such, in order to secure the auto generated and manual endpoints I have been using a role based approach and a custom `PermissionEvaluator` to handle object specific auth checks. This works but is too cumbersome and fails when I need a filtered and paginated response. So, I am planning to implement ACL. Now, I have a rather complicated flow of authorisation for an entity.

The users are mapped to a profile entity(MANY TO MANY). The `target` entity is also mapped to a separate profile entity(MANY TO MANY) and these 2 profile entities are mapped to each other(MANY TO MANY). To check if a particular user has permission over a `target` entity object, I need to go through the relationships in my application logic, in my `PermissionEvaluator`.

Now, if I decide to implement this in ACL only, I am confused as to how to best to do this. The preliminary idea that I had is to create the object list directly in the ACL tables for each user(principle). This would mean that I would need to update the ACL tables everytime with new objects if a permission is changed. Is this a correct approach? Is there a better way to do this? Is it even ok to modify the ACL tables frequently?

Summary: If the logic to check if a user has access over an object is complicated and requires data from other tables, how do I handle it efficiently using ACL?

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on an ACL extension for Spring Data JPA/Rest which handles all of your problems - and many more. It take some time to learn how does it work, but it still needs much less time than creating all of these features for yourself.

You can set up the access rules using annotations in the entity classes - and that's all. it will affect the auto-generated and manual endpoints and even the Data JPA repository-methods.

[Spring Data JPA ACL](https://github.com/BerryCloud/spring-data-jpa-acl/tree/master/acl)